# Qt одновременный показ нескольких вкладок

Tags: qt

Пишу приложение на Qt, нужно использовать виджет, который позволяет создавать несколько вкладок, перемещать вкладку вне окна приложения и, таким образом, одновременно работать с двумя вкладками. Как я поняла, читая документацию, QTabWidget не позволяет такое сделать. Есть ли другой готовый виджет? Или нужно писать самой, тогда какие методы нужно переопределить?

Answer (score 1):

**LXA** всё верно говорит. Разве что `QDockWidget`, а не DockWidget.

Позволяет легко создавать отдельные окошки, прикрепляемые к определённым областям окна `QMainWindow` (`QDockArea` если не ошибаюсь). Обязательно наличие centralWidget. Виджеты можно располагать в виде отдельных окон, либо в tab style, как `QTabWidget`. Перетаскивать и сворачивать при необходимости.

Есть некоторые проблемы в тонкой настройке стиля (stylesheet qss). Например, не работают margin и border. Заголовок можно создать свой и подгрузить в QDockWidget.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам следует использовать MDI (многооконную область), либо DockWidget ( который можно сделать перемещаемым).